# Custom Views in iPad Settings UI similar to Mail App

Tags: ios, ipad, settings.bundle

What I am trying to do is similar to Mail App settings' Add New Account.
If you go to settings for Mail App and click on "Add Account..." and select Gmail, you will be presented with a "modal dialogue" to add a new mail account.

I want to do exactly similar to that for my app settings.
I have searched in forums and documentation and did not find any references to custom views or modal view in settings UI. All I can find is to add a child plist file and some simple input fields. These settings can only be static and not dynamic.

does it mean we can't tweak the settings app to have modal dialogs or custom view ?

if thats the case, can we atleast push new rows (new inputs) into settings after user does something on the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, settings bundles are completely static. If you need a dynamic settings dialog, you have to do it yourself within the app.